# Problem in understanding a syntax for 3D simulation with matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I am trying to understand a code for 3D simulation. But i failed to understand specific syntax in the code. The code is given here.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d as p3
import matplotlib.animation as animation



def update_lines(num, dataLines, lines):
    for line, data in zip(lines, dataLines):
           line.set_data(data[0:2,0:num])
        line.set_3d_properties(data[2,0:num])
        line.set_marker("o")
    return lines



fig = plt.figure()
ax = p3.Axes3D(fig)


t = np.linspace(-2*np.pi,2*np.pi,50)
x1, y1, z1 = np.cos(t), np.sin(t), t/t.max()
x2, y2, z2 = t/t.max(), np.cos(t), np.sin(t)
data = np.array([[x1,y1,z1],[x2,y2,z2]])
print(data)

   #ax=fig.add_subplot(221,projection='3d')
lines = [ax.plot(dat[0, 0:1], dat[1, 0:1], dat[2, 0:1])[0] for dat in data]

ax.set_xlim(-1.1,1.1)
ax.set_ylim(-1.1,1.1)
ax.set_zlim(-1.1,1.1)
ax.set_xlabel("x")
ax.set_ylabel("y")
ax.set_zlabel("z")


line_ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update_lines, frames=100, fargs=(data, lines),
                                   interval=100, blit=False, repeat=True)
plt.show()
```

can anyone explain this line?

```
lines = [ax.plot(dat[0, 0:1], dat[1, 0:1], dat[2, 0:1])[0] for dat in data]
```

i understand the we are trying to plot the initial points in the 3D space as we cant send empty arrays here but what is that '[0]' doing there? and why we are using the for loop?
and the other problem is

```
for line, data in zip(lines, dataLines):
```

how is it working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot.html) the function `ax.plot()` returns

> lines: A list of Line2D objects representing the plotted data.

The line

```
lines = [ax.plot(dat[0, 0:1], dat[1, 0:1], dat[2, 0:1])[0] for dat in data]
```

is a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) that puts the first (and only) line in the plot into another list. That other list is accessed later in the update function.

The other line

```
for line, data in zip(lines, dataLines):
```

iterates through two iterables (list, tuple, etc.) and in each iteration returns the values from these arrays. First iteration - first value from both arrays. Second iteration  - second element from the arrays. More info e.g. [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_zip.asp).